# Unexpected behavior when running pop {r11,pc}

Tags: assembly, arm

I am debugging a simple program using gdb,
And I am getting unexpected behavior when I am running the instruction pop {r11,pc}
The stack before the execution of the instruction is:

[Stack before the instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggt7H.png)

I expect the value of the pc after the execution of the instruction to be 0x42424243
but for some reason it is 0x42424242

Anyone has any suggestion about why this may happen?

The program is execute on a RPi

I tried multiple values and couldn't find any consistency in the last byte of the pc register

Comment: No because it also happens when the LSB is even.

Comment: please post the text in the question not pictures.

Comment: what is the actual question here?    the lsbit indicates which mode to return to.

Comment: the msbit is consumed by the logic the program counter in arm mode will always have the two lsbits of zero and in thumb mode lowest bit.  the bit is for the instruction not for the pc.

Comment: RPi implies raspberry pi of which there is the pico which is a cortex-m based and some that are armv6 based some armv7a and armv8 based.  The latter has an armv7a compatiblity mode.  So the cortexm comment here can be relevant for the pi but also just how the non-64 bit instructions work.

Comment: clearly if you look at the instruction set there would be a massive failure if the lsbit(s) of the pc were non-zero.  and you can trivially test this in various ways to confirm it.

Comment: this is why there is a T bit in the psr, which is also in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of the thumb capable cores cortex-m or full sized.  The lsbit of a branch destination address or other documented mixed mode capable instructions (add pc,r0,r1), is used to indicate which mode to switch to or stay in.  The lsbit is consumed by the instruction and placed in the T bit in the psr it does not go into the pc itself.

The instruction set would clearly be documented as such if this were valid, but simple experiments will show it is not the case.  As you have demonstrated.